# Why can’t I create a custom validator using JavaScript in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this piece of code. It should implement my custom validations, but it does not work:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode = "Multiple">
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Required"
ClientValidationFunction = "ValidateListBox"></asp:CustomValidator>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ValidateListBox(sender, args) {
    var options = document.getElementById("<%=ListBox1.ClientID%>").options;
    if (options.length > 0) {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }       
}
</script>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

I used Firebug, but I got no result.

Comment: Your code seems to be working when listbox1 is empty

Comment: wrong tags! not java but javascript... how people can mix these things

Comment: @javagirl: probably something to do with “Java” being in both terms.

Comment: @Paul Thank you very much Captain Obvious

Comment: @javagirl: You asked the question.

Comment: @Paul did you ever hear about rhetorical questions? :D btw this question is rhetorical too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have revised the code and it appears that you have spellings mistakes in your code i have edit it :)